# How to authenticate to Spring Boot OAuth2 JWT from ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I have created a Spring Boot OAuth2 JWT MySQL as specified  [here](https://github.com/cpapidas/Spring-Boot-OAuth2-JWT-MySQL) and found the user is authenticating when i run the curl request like below.

```
curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=papidakos123&username=papidakos&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"
```

Now i need to use this as a back-end for my ionic application, but i am new to this ionic application development and don't know how to authenticate to my spring security oauth2 server from the ionic application.I have googled it but found most of them are using social signing with google,facebook,etc.I didn't have any idea about authentication process from the ionic front end and storing of the access and refresh tokens and assigned roles.Please help me to develop this with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `http` module you can do a `POST` request to the server, and then you can store your token in localstorage using [NativeStorage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/)

```
constructor(public nativeStorage : NativeStorage){

}

postRequest() {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
  });


  let postParams = {
    password: papidakos123,
    username: papidakos,
    grant_type: password,
    scope = read % 20 write,
    client_secret = 123456,
    client_id = clientapp
  }

  this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token", postParams, options)
    .subscribe(data => {
      if(data.success){
      //Handle success
      //this.nativeStorage.set('token',data.token).catch(err=>{
       //handle storage error
      });
     }
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Depending on the response you can use RxJS to set the login state of the user. Refer this [Github Source](https://github.com/ionic-zone/ionic-auth-replaysubject)

Comment: can you show me a complete example with login pages.I am new to the ionic development.

Comment: I added a source to my answer. Please refer that.

Comment: Ok thankyou but is it secure to use it with http instead of https

Comment: `http` is just an object which is used to send requests. If you want to secure your request, you can setup SSL on your server and just use `https://` instead of `http://`

Comment: You can use the above code in your Authenticator Provider. I recommend watching a few videos and do some research on how to implement a basic login system using Facebook / Google OAuth2 , you can then use that to your liking.

Comment: I didn't want to login with facebook/google oauth2.I just want to authenticate the user with my spring boot oauth2 server with mysql database.

Comment: I understand that. But first learn how to implement OAuth2 Flow. And then you can do it for Spring Boot, because I see that you haven't had experience with that on ionic 2

Comment: yes.you are right this is the first time am developing an ionic hybrid app